# Shell exclamation mark command

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

What does this command do?

```
!g++
```

For the history command:

```
!12
```

It runs command #12 of the history, but what about `g++`, or another:

```
!cat filename
```

Comment: Wrong site. StackOverflow is for programming questions, not usage.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators

Comment: @tink Using command line is not exactly programming... but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Bash manual, "Event Designators"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators):

> `!string`
>
> Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list starting with `string`.

This means that `!g++` runs the last command that began with `g++`, calling the GNU C++ compiler:

```
$ g++ -o myprog -flto -O3 foo.o bar.o baz.o -lgfortran
...
(g++ does its job here)
...
$ vim test
...
(other commands)
...
$ !g++
g++ -o myprog -flto -O3 foo.o bar.o baz.o -lgfortran  <-- same command as before
```

`!cat filename`, on the other hands, doesn't make a lot of sense as it's already a complete command. Unless there was a super complicated pipe after that command the last time, of course, which the event designator would then repeat.